# auxiliary in inversion without a negation

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I thought we must use auxiliary verbs in sentences with inversion only when we have an explicit (not, never) or implicit (only if, hardly, little) negation. But I have come across the next sentence:

**1.** *Dearly do I love you*.

Why must we use "*do*" here?

---

Why can't we say:

**2.** *Dearly love I you*.

---

Thanks!

Comment: In 1. the "do" is to emphasise the positive polarity of the clause; it is optional. 2. is ungrammatical, since such inversion is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to use **do** in this context.

It is sufficient to write:

> Dearly I love you

as an alternative to **I love you dearly**.

But there are many contexts - often poetic, philosophical or reflective - in which we insert the auxiliary after the introductory adverb to create a certain mood:

> Painfully do we learn the lessons of life
>   Wearily does he make his way home.
>   Quietly does she sleep in her bed.

However, **Dearly love I you** is not grammatical. You need to write either:

> Dearly do I love you
>   or
>   I do love you dearly.

Note that placing the adverb **dearly** at the end of the sentence creates a different nuance, as though someone were insisting on his/her love in the face of doubts.